# Query DateTime Varchar in Nanoseconds level in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, sql-timestamp

I have a Postgres table with a column, that has DateTime values as varchar.

```
date_column 
"2023/10/26 17:20:00.100100000"
"2023/10/26 17:20:00.100100000"
```

To filter this column in microsecond level, I use a SQL query like below.

```
SELECT * FROM date_data
 WHERE TO_TIMESTAMP(date_column , 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:ss.US')  
 BETWEEN  TIMESTAMP '2023-01-01 09:09:09.000000000' AND TIMESTAMP '2024-01-11 09:09:09.000000000';
```

As in the above query, I use the TO_TIMESTAMP method to convert the DateTime varchar to TimeStamp type.
My issue is Postgres doesn't support converting to Timestamp in nanosecond level. It supports only upto micrsecond level. 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:ss.**US**'

Comment: The resulution of a `TIMESTAMP` in PostgreSQL is *1 microsecond*, what is the question?

Answer (score 2):

As you already pointed out, [nano (1e-9)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_prefix#List_of_SI_prefixes) is beyond [PostgreSQL precision limit of micro (1e-6)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-TABLE). You can consider [`timestamp9` extension](https://github.com/optiver/timestamp9) that offers a more granular, nanosecond-precise version of `timestamp`.

Otherwise, anything above the limit has to get extracted to a separate column or bundled into an [additional field of a custom type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtype.html), neither of which is pretty: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/ET2UqA_Z)

```sql
create type timestamp_plus_nano as (ts timestamp, nano smallint);
select ('2023-01-01 09:09:09.123456',789)::timestamp_plus_nano;
```

Both of these force you to compare 4 values/fields against 2 instead of 2 against 1, which isn't very convenient.